# Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable with null-conditional operator (?.)

Tags: c#, resharper, null-conditional-operator

I think this on is a false positive from resharper, but I'd like to get someone else's opinion. Maybe I am missing something.

I found this behavior in both Resharper 9.2 and 10.

Consider this class :

```
   public class Foo
   {
      public IEnumerable<string> SomeList { get; set; }
   }
```

And this method :

```
  public void Method(Foo thisFooCanBeNull)
  {
     List<string> theList = thisFooCanBeNull?.SomeList?.ToList();
     if (theList != null && theList.Count > 0) //Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable
     {
        foreach (string s in theList) //Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable
        {
           //Do something with list.
        }
     }
  }
```

`theList.Count` and the `foreach` trigger the warnig, but since I did a `ToList()`, this is impossible, right?

It does not trigger the warning if I change `thisFooCanBeNull?.SomeList?.ToList()` by `thisFooCanBeNull.SomeList?.ToList()`, but since "this foo can be null", well, I don't want to do the change.

Is anybody seeing a problem with this code?

Comment: Result of `?.ToList()` can be `null`. You can add `?? new List<string>()` at the end to ensure what `theList` can't be `null` and remove `if` condition (`foreach` will never fail in such case).

Comment: @Sinatr : yes, but that would be just a trick to hide a warning that probably should not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see a case in which this should enumerate multiple times. I would tend to believe it is a R# bug related to the still new-ish ?. operator, especially since swapping that for the normal dot operator removes the error.

You may want to double check that it does not actually enumerate multiple times though, by putting a breakpoint or debug statement in whatever the source for your IEnumerable is.